# Getting "Can't configure anyRequest after itself" error after upgrading spring-security-web to 5.6.9

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm getting the below exception after upgrading `spring-security-web` dependency from `4.2.20.RELEASE` to `5.6.9`. The error is

> Can't configure anyRequest after itself

Given below is the detailed logging information.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:76) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at com.premierinc.trs.user.config.ProvisioningSecurityConfig.configure(ProvisioningSecurityConfig.java:32) ~[user-1.5.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at com.premierinc.trs.user.config.ProvisioningSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b2eea9c.init(<generated>) ~[user-1.5.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.6.9.jar:5.6.9]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 64 more
```

Here is my `ProvisioningSecurityConfig.java` file. The above log gives exception at line 32 in this  code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ProvisioningSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProvisioningSecurityConfig.class);
    @Value("${provision.ldapGroupWithServiceAccess:SERVICE_ACCESS_APP_PROV}")
    private String ldapGroupWithServiceAccess;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        logger.info(String.format("provision.ldapGroupWithServiceAccess->%s", ldapGroupWithServiceAccess));
        http.csrf().disable();

        // Do not create sessions - authenticate user on every request
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        final String relativeProvisionEndpointPattern = VUserUris.ROOT + VUserUris.PROVISION;
        final String fullProvisionEndpointPattern = CommonUris.SERVLET_ROOT + relativeProvisionEndpointPattern;
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(fullProvisionEndpointPattern + "/**", fullProvisionEndpointPattern + "*",
                        relativeProvisionEndpointPattern + "/**", relativeProvisionEndpointPattern + "*")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .anonymous().disable();

        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(fullProvisionEndpointPattern + "/**", fullProvisionEndpointPattern + "*",
                        relativeProvisionEndpointPattern + "/**", relativeProvisionEndpointPattern + "*")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole(ldapGroupWithServiceAccess); //line 32
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationConfiguration.class);
        @Value("${provision.ldapUrl:ldap://ldapserver:589/}")
        private String ldapUrl;

        @Value("${provision.ldapUserDnPattern:uid={0},ou=applicationIds,ou=Users,o=vishnu.com}")
        private String ldapUserDnPattern;

        @Value("${provision.ldapGroupSearchBase:ou=Groups,o=vishnu.com}")
        private String ldapGroupSearchBase;

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            logger.info(String.format("provision.ldapUrl->%s", ldapUrl));
            logger.info(String.format("provision.ldapUserDnPattern->%s", ldapUserDnPattern));
            logger.info(String.format("provision.ldapGroupSearchBase->%s", ldapGroupSearchBase));
            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapUrl);
            context.afterPropertiesSet();
            auth.ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern)
                    .groupSearchBase(ldapGroupSearchBase)
                    .contextSource(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `anyRequest` twice.

Comment: Its important to note previous you were overriding the initial `.anyRequest().authenticated()` call. E.g. it only ever allowed the LDAP group. This is not a breaking change in your app, this change is essentially just a guardrail to tell you that you expectations of what youre configuring is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `anyRequest` twice, combine your authorization rules into one call, like so:

```java
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers(fullProvisionEndpointPattern + "/**", fullProvisionEndpointPattern + "*",
                        relativeProvisionEndpointPattern + "/**", relativeProvisionEndpointPattern + "*")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().hasRole(ldapGroupWithServiceAccess) // here you have to decide if it is just authenticated() or hasRole(...)
        .and()
    .httpBasic()
        .and()
    .anonymous().disable();
```

Comment: hasRole implicitly means that the user has to be authenticated

Comment: So using hasRole alone should be enough right?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough. Please accept the answer if it has fixed your problem this way other can find it faster